# Wrong order when upload to firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm trying to add 25 values in my `firebase` scheme. I tried doing a simple `for loop` (in `ios` using `swift`) like this:

```
for var index = 1; index < 26; ++index {
        let dict = ["FullName" : "\(index)"]
        firebaseRef.childByAppendingPath("\(index)").setValue(dict)
}
```

All the data gets uploaded, but it's out of order. What can I do to fix that?

Here's the order that it goes to:

[image]

Comment: It's perfectly in order! ...alphabetically, that is...

Comment: Oh, I get it, why it was in that order, I was wondering why is was so weird like that! How can I get it in a regulare order?

Comment: Let's not say things like "out of order" and "regular order". Your values are in alphabetical order and it sounds like you want them to be in numerical order. There's a good reason Firebase makes this non-trivial: https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/saving-data.html#section-lists. But if you insist, you can probably pass an array of numbers to `setValue()`